# how to insert generated html table data into database in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

How I can insert all data from a generated HTML table into my database using PHP?

I have tried with a foreach loop, but it gives me an error all the time.

I have this code in JavaScript to adding a new row using a button:

```
    var i=1;
    function addRow()
    {
              var tbl = document.getElementById('table1');
              var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
              var iteration = lastRow - 1;
              var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

              var firstCell = row.insertCell(0);
              var el = document.createElement('input');
              el.type = 'text';
              el.name = 'to' + i;
              el.id = 'to' + i;
              el.size = 40;
              firstCell.appendChild(el);

              var secondCell = row.insertCell(1);
              var el2 = document.createElement('input');
              el2.type = 'text';
              el2.name = 'cost' + i;
              el2.id = 'cost' + i;
              el2.size = 40;
              secondCell.appendChild(el2);

             frm.h.value=i;
             i++;
    }
```

And this is my HTML code:

```
<table id="table1" width="40%" border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td><strong>To Address</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Delivery Cost</strong></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input name="to" type="text" id="to" size="40"/></td>
        <td><input name="cost" type="text" id="cost" size="40"/></td>
    </tr>

</table>
<br/><br/>

<input style="float: right;background-color: #57a000;height: 30px;font-weight: bold; font-family: cursive;margin-left: 10px;"
    type="submit" value="Save All" name="SaveCost"/>

<input style="float: right;background-color: #57a000;height: 30px;font-weight: bold; font-family: cursive;"
    type="button" value="Add New Place" onclick="addRow();"/>


<input name="h" type="hidden" id="h" value="0"/>
```

Finally I want to write some PHP to insert all the data from the generated HTML table into my database.

Comment: What PHP code have you tried and what error does it give you?

Comment: And how are you sending that table to the server?